# Custom close votes broken in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, ios-app, custom-close-reasons

On the website, after a user votes to close as off-topic for a custom reason, future voters can select that reason. On the iOS app, however, they cannot. Instead, they are given two custom close options:

[image: annotated screenshot]

This appears to be a bug.

**EDIT:** this also happens on the iPhone:

[image]

Comment: That's specifically the still-in-beta (I think) iPad app; the iPhone app, aside from not including the *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because"*, works as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm using version 1.3.1 of the app, released April 26; there's no mention of this being a beta version. You are correct that the above screenshot is from an iPad. I have not yet confirmed your statement that it works correctly on the iPhone.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have confirmed that this affects the iPhone app, as well, as shown in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in prod.

The logic for displaying titles for filled out "Other" questions was in the close options popup UI.  I've moved it to the model so it can be shared between the UI and the API.  Incidentally, they were also acting the same as the last option because they were being incorrectly marked as `requires_comment`.